# PowerShell Script - picking up hidden folders / files

Tags: powershell

Team --
I have a PowerShell script to capture the inventory of a shared drive regardless of the number of sub-folders and to then return a results file.
What's odd is that my results file is capturing files that I can't see within the folder itself (please see the image as an example).

The path is shown in the Excel file and the shared folder layered on top.  When I navigate down the folder path, I reach a point where the next folder "One Drive - Dell Technologies" (in green) is not there.

I've tried clicking 'show hidden folders' but it still doesn't appear.

Any ideas why the script would be capturing files that say they are there -- but I'm unable to actually navigate / or see them?

[image]

Comment: Can you navigate to that directory by typing out the full name? Shared drives will be tricky if the data changes between the time you check the folder and the time you run the script. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: Might be a "system folder". They are hidden even more. For them, you have to enable _show system files_ to view them in Windows Explorer. In PowerShell, you can check if the attributes of that folder not only contain `h`, but also `s`.

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse - this is part of a file clean up effort.  My script builds an inventory file with the "age" of the file.  Things older than X years old have to be deleted if there's no business validation to keep them.

So I can type in the folder name and open up every folder on the path until I come to the one that I can't see in the first place.  System error says the folder cannot be found.

Comment: @stackprotector - good suggestion.  I've changed the system settings to show system folders but it still does not show my the folder I was expecting.

Since it's the corporate One Drive, I'm wondering if my IT department has something hidden that non-IT users can't see.  But this is all guess work right now.

Comment: @Matthew Please post the output of `Get-Item -Path 'path\to\One Drive - Dell Technologies' -Force | Select-Object -Property *`. Otherwise, there is no way to debug this.

Comment: Team -- found the resolution.  A colleague had moved such a folder onto the shared drive (before my scan) and then removed them the next day (after the scan was complete).  They didn't say anything about doing this until I told them I had engaged outside help to resolve.... PEBCAK 101 strikes again... or Occam's razor 101.  Either way, thank you and I'm sorry for the wild goose chase.